# find all possible combinations of letters in a string in python

Tags: python, string, substring

I have a string in python,
I need to find all the possible ways any substring of that string (including itself)
could be selected. A substring (for my purposes) does not have to be contiguous, in the original string -- it could have gaps. 
Eg: `"frogman"` is one of the many substrings of `"froghuman'` under this definition.

For example of the would function:
If my string is `"abcd"`, the output should be:

```
[ "a", "b", "c", "d", "ab", "ac", "ad", "bc", "bd", "cd", "abc", "abd", "acd", "bcd", "abcd" ]
```

Comment: Hint: https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html

Comment: look at [`powerset()` itertools' recipe](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes): `list(map(''.join, powerset('abcd')))`

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian I think your solution would also include 'ac' as an option (could be wrong).

Comment: Would the simplest way not just be to use a double for loop (in a comprehension or not), i.e. for i in range(n-1) for j in range(i+1,n)

Comment: @user2539336: look at the expected output in the question (`'ac'` is present). The correct term would be "subsequence" instead of "substring" here.

Comment: This question is not too broad. It's also being discussed on Meta: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/283177/is-too-broad-a-valid-reason-to-close-a-question-that-doesnt-show-any-research

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Your example input/output suggests that you are looking for a [power set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_set). You could [generate a power set for a string using `itertools` module in Python](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes):

```
from itertools import chain, combinations

def powerset(iterable):
    "powerset([1,2,3]) --> () (1,) (2,) (3,) (1,2) (1,3) (2,3) (1,2,3)"
    s = list(iterable)
    return chain.from_iterable(combinations(s, r) for r in range(len(s)+1))

print(list(map(''.join, powerset('abcd'))))
```

#### Output

```
['',
 'a',
 'b',
 'c',
 'd',
 'ab',
 'ac',
 'ad',
 'bc',
 'bd',
 'cd',
 'abc',
 'abd',
 'acd',
 'bcd',
 'abcd']
```

Note: the output includes the empty string.